# Authentication and Security in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

We are building system which queries Hive table. Our Service Layer will construct Hive Query based on User Selection on UI, We have some security related questions over here

•   Is it Ok to pass Hive Dynamic Query constructed at service layer to a UDF/HQL in Hive ?
•   Are there any SQL Injection kind of Scenarios occurs in Hive, We are Hive 0.14, it contains delete and update statements.
•   How can we manage Role Authorization to access table only like perform Read instead of Write and Delete. Is there way to manage permission for Hive table. Or will it be managed by HCatalog?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass a dynamic query to Hive using PowerShell APIs. Check out https://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com/

Hive 14 does support Insert, Update and Delete. Check out https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-5317

Role authorization is currently not supported by HDInsight (as of 6/2015) but is something we are actively investigating and hope to bring to market soon.

Answer (score 0):

Role based authorization and auditing with record, fields and cell level control and dynamic masking is available on hadoop with bluetalon policy engine.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: BlueTalon Policy Engine is available in Azure Marketplace that works with HD Insight.